# Making a web page from Javascript only

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have been given an assignment to rip down an existing HTML page and rebuild a new one just with Javascript. So I have taken down the page leaving me with the following:

```
<html> 
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div id="masterDiv>
      <div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src = Javascript.js></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

From here I want to structure a new site with a header, footer, left column, right column and a body in the middle with only Javascript (I have appended the spare div to the master div)

Comment: An interesting, if pointless exercise - did you have a question you need help with?

Comment: Needs more [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yeah the question is how to structure the new site, should I make like 6 divs and separate them with padding and if so should I append each div to the previously made div

Comment: So are you asking how to technically do it? or what we think would look prettiest?

Comment: Im asking how to do it, I know how to add the CSS and images etc, its just getting the structure I want up to start working on

Comment: `the question is how to structure the new site` - how should the new site be structured. `should I make like 6 divs and separate them with padding` - if that's the requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you really need to do this is

- [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)
- [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)
- [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

Here is a simple example of these three:

```js
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.textContent = "Hello World";
document.querySelector("#container").appendChild(div);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah this is what I have been playing with,  should I make like 6 divs and separate them with padding and if so should I append each div to the previously made div

Comment: Well, padding always looks nice. As does margin, but it is important to understand the difference (padding being the inner whitespace / margin being the outer whitespace). That aside, do not "daisy chain" the 6 divs, it will result in an odd looking structure. Make a holder, and then place what logically goes in that holder inside. Then append the holders in series to the document body. Structuring a page though, that is highly opinion based, and everyone has their own view (ever heard of geocities? :D).

Comment: I was planning to append all other divs to the masterDiv, however I cannot seem to append more than 1 to it, should I use something else?
I havent heard of that :/

Comment: You can append as many divs to the masterDiv as the hardware can handle, probably to the tune of 80,000... give or take. More than likely you ran into an issue of accidentally reusing a variable or of not connecting an in memory element to the DOM.

Comment: Okay, I will continue on that path then, good to know Im not doing it without some sort of a possible outcome.
Thanks to all :)